# R Bookdown: Tabbed headings

Tags: r, bookdown

How use tabbed heading in **bookdown** like as RMarkdown?

in RMarkdown:

```
# heading1 {.tabset}

## tab1
content1

## tab2
content2
```

[image]

---

## Same code in bookdown:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/393

yihui: This feature is not supported in bookdown (because it is not a portable feature, e.g. not available to LaTeX/PDF output). Sorry.

Comment: Is this feature not possible to implement in gitbook?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible to implement using HTML+CSS+JS when using `gitbook` model. If you still want to handle pdf output, you will need to create `LaTeX` environments as explained [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-blocks.html).

You can have a start with the [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp) solution and adapt it in `bookdown` context.

## HTML implementation

A pure HTML implementation would be:

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Tabs</h2>
<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

## How it adapts in bookdown

This can be adapted in `bookdown`

### 1. In a CSS file

In let's say `style.css`, put this lines:

```css
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

### 2. In a `header.html` file

In a HTML file, let's say `header.html`:

```html
<script>
function unrolltab(evt, tabName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

### 3. Declare these files in `_output.yml`:

You must declare CSS and JS snippets in this file:

```yaml
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: ./css/style.css
  includes:
    in_header: ./header.html
```

### 4. Use it in your bookdown

You could directly write

```html
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

However, there is a more suitable solution when using `R Markdown` (that could help if you defined the appropriate `LaTeX` styles. It is based on [custom blocks](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-blocks.html).

```
::: {.tab}
<button class="tablinks" onclick="unrolltab(event, 'London')">London</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="unrolltab(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="unrolltab(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
::: {#London .tabcontent}
#### London {-}
London is the capital city of England
:::
::: {#Paris .tabcontent}
#### Paris  {-}
Paris is the capital city of France
:::
::: {#Tokyo .tabcontent}
#### Tokyo  {-}
Tokyo is the capital city of Japan
:::
:::
```

For instance, putting text between `:::{#London .tabcontent}` and `:::` will wrap the content within a `<div id="London" class="tabcontent">` block